Shutdown all nodes using rclpy
shutdown alll nodes
Above talks about shutting down nodes in rospy how do I do proper clean up in rclpy.
I tried:
        def shutdown_nodes(self):
            self.get_logger().info("Shutting down the node and ROS.")
            shutdown_message = Bool(data=True)
            self.shutdown_publisher.publish(shutdown_message)
            rclpy.shutdown()


    def main():
        rclpy.init()
        learning_ddpg = LearningDDPG()
        rclpy.spin(learning_ddpg)
        learning_ddpg.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


But i got error:
rclpy.spin(learning_ddpg)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 218, in spin
    executor = get_global_executor() if executor is None else executor
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 102, in get_global_executor
    __executor = SingleThreadedExecutor()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 721, in __init__
    super().__init__(context=context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._guard = GuardCondition(
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/guard_condition.py", line 23, in __init__
    with self._context.handle:
AttributeError: __enter__
Exception ignored in: <function Executor.__del__ at 0x78d0a3ce17e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 243, in __del__
    if self._sigint_gc is not None:
AttributeError: 'SingleThreadedExecutor' object has no attribute '_sigint_gc'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

